# Date Functions in Android Client for Azure Mobile Service

Tags: android, date, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure Mobile Service which returns date to an Android Client in this format
"Sat Sep 27 22:48:48 PDT 2014"

I want to calculate the difference between this returned date and today's date. After much iterations here is my current function.

```
 public String calculateDayDifference(String DateFromAzure){

        SimpleDateFormat AzureDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd H:m:s yyyy");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        String result;

        try {
           String currentDate = AzureDateFormat.format(System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000L);
           Date presentDate = AzureDateFormat.parse(currentDate);
           Date billDueDate = AzureDateFormat.parse(DateFromAzure);
           long diff = billDueDate.getTime() - presentDate.getTime(); 
           result = Long.toString(diff);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            result = Long.toString(- 1);
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  result;
    }
```

And here is how I call this function from my Adapter's getView() method

```
 viewHolder.txtNumberDays.setText(mDateFunctions.calculateDayDifference(
                viewHolder.billSummary.getBillDueDate().toString()))
```

And here is the Java class field that maps to the date column in the Mobile Service table.

```
  @SerializedName("billDueDate")
    private Date BillDueDate;
```

No matter how I tweak it, it give me negative result like so. How can I re-write the method above to return the difference between today's date and the date returned from Azure Mobile Service table?

[image: Azure Mobile Service Android Display Date]

Comment: Look at your code: the results are allways -1, which means you have a ParseException. Avoid swallowing exceptions, at least log them. Also the difference are in milliseconds, not in days.

Comment: Thank you, on examining the exception it is throwing an unparseable date exception on the the date format I got back from the Azure web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, from the AMS Android SDK source code I can see that the SDK handles formatting and parsing of dates automatically so what is returned is a valid java.util.date object.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/android/src/sdk/src/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/DateSerializer.java

With this realization I just called getTime() method on the returned date so I can compare it again current date which can be obtained from System.CurrentTimeMillis(). I then converted the result to int and that was with. Long learning experience. Its not the most efficient way to handle this but it works for. Here is the code

```
  mBillDueDateService.mBillTable
                .execute(new TableQueryCallback<Bill>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<Bill> result, int count,
                                    Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                if (exception == null){
                   for (Bill bill : result){
                       long timeInLong = bill.getBillDueDate().getTime();
                       long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                       long diffTime = timeInLong - currentTime;
                       long diffDays = diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
                       int daysdiff = (int) diffDays;
                       Log.i(TAG, "Bill Name " + bill.getBillName() + "" + "Due in " + daysdiff + "days");
                       bill.setDaysBeforeDueDate(daysdiff);
                        mUpcomingBillAdapter.add(bill);
                    }
```